# Youtube and Netflix log me out even though I enabled cookies

Tags: firefox, youtube, cookies, netflix

I have an annoying thing here. In Firefox, I chose to delete cookies after I close firefox, and entered some exceptions which allow the cookie to be saved. This works well for some forums where I dont want to login every time. But for some reason, although they are in the allowed exception list, I always need to login on Youtube and Netflix. Do I need to whitelist some other page, or do they use some different way of storing login credentials?

(Sorry for writing this in stackexchange first)
Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to whitelist other domains, big sites like Youtube which are using accounts across multiple Google properties sites often are not doing the authentication on the primary domain and are instead redirecting your browser to another domain for authentication. This is also what allows you to sign into one site like Youtube and then also be signed in on Google Drive, Gmail, etc.

For Google properties I believe the authentication site is accounts.google.com so you would need to whitelist that. Netflix may be doing something similar but I'm less familiar with their authentication.